# Click button and hide element "brother" and show another

Tags: jquery, html

This code works for all but not for the specific element on press button..

HTML:

```
<div id="ProductsIndex">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="product-detail"></div>
        <div class="prod-box"></div>
        <a class="btn-detail" href=""> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#ProductsIndex .product .btn-detail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#ProductsIndex .product .prod-box').hide('slow');
    $('#ProductsIndex .product .product-detail').show('slow');

    $('#ProductsIndex .product .product-detail .fa-times').click(function(e) {
        $('#ProductsIndex .product  .product-detail').hide('slow');
        $('#ProductsIndex .product .prod-box').show('slow');
    });
});
```

This works for all elements but I need for specific element when I press the button.

Comment: What do you mean *"works for all elements"*? where are the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind event in event handler.

Use

```
$('.product .btn-detail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest(".product");
    parent.find(".prod-box'").hide('slow');
    parent.find(".product-detail").show('slow');
});

$('.product .fa-times').click(function(e) {
    var parent = $(this).closest(".product");
    parent.find(".prod-box'").show('slow');
    parent.find(".product-detail").hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: +1 This is the right way of doing this. registering an event inside of another one event handler is a worst coding practice..

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, don't nest the attachment of one click handler inside the other, otherwise the inner attachment will be made repeatedly, every time the outer handler fires.

Secondly, you can exploit jQuery's `.closest()` and `.find()` to traverse the DOM, with the clicked node as the initial reference point.

```
$('#ProductsIndex .product .btn-detail').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("#ProductsIndex")
        .find(".prod-box").hide('slow').end()
        .find(".product-detail").show('slow');

});
$('#ProductsIndex .product .product-detail .fa-times').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest("#ProductsIndex")
        .find(".product-detail").hide('slow').end()
        .find(".prod-box").show('slow');
});
```

NOTE: Judicious use of `.end()` avoids unnecessary assignments.